# Upper bound on sum of sine with integer frequencies

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to find the max value over $t$ of

$$\sum_{k} a_k \sin (kt),$$

where $k$ is positive and odd.

If the exact max cannot be found in terms of the real coefficients $a_k$, an upper bound for the sum would also help.

Finding the derivative with respect to $t$ and forcing it to zero did not help, as finding all the roots of

$$\sum_k \frac{a_k}{k} \sin (k t)$$

seems to be at least just as difficult.

The coefficients $a_k$ are bounded with

$$|a_k|<\frac{1}{k},$$ but this bound is not tight, so I would prefer not to use it.

Any ideas where I should look?